# Could a jet engine theoretically ingest not only oxidizer but fuel (on planets like jupiter)

Tags: jet-engine

Jet engines work by ingesting oxygen from the air and combusting it with an onboard fuel source like kerosene. But, on planets like Jupiter, with an abundance of hydrogen, would it be possible to remove the onboard fuel source and ingest both oxygen and hydrogen, carrying no fuel at all? This is assuming that the plane would be able to withstand very high pressures, and if Jupiter doesn't have the right amount of oxygen, any other planets that have the right atmosphere to support it.

Comment: "*any other planets that have the right atmosphere*": There are none in the solar system. Earth with its load of O2 is really an exception, thanks to photosynthesis ([GOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxidation_Event)). There is no other known place where a significant quantity of 02 can be found.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Jupiter has hydrogen, but not oxygen. So you would need to bring your own oxygen, and essentially have just replaced what you use as "fuel."

If the atmosphere was, by itself, flammable then a jet engine should work. For a brief period of time before you set the atmosphere on fire.

Atmospheres don't tend to be flammable, for what are pretty obvious reasons if you think about it.

Comment: Wouldn't an atmosphere of pure flammable gas with no oxygen be safe for a jet engine that burned atmospheric gas and added oxygen in the way Earth jets add fuel, since after combustion in the jet, there would be no oxygen to burn the atmosphere further?

Comment: @Someone I think that's the point of the first paragraph here. An atmosphere with fuel but no oxygen (Jupiter's) can exist, and your aircraft would have to provide its own O2. An atmosphere with oxygen but no fuel (i.e. Earth's) can exist, and the aircraft brings its fuel. An atmosphere with both fuel ***and*** oxygen can exist until the first spark, and then... well, you'll burn up the fuel until it or the oxygen runs out, and then you're back to one of the first two cases.

Comment: Not sure if it would matter as the *ratio* would be the same when compressed, but *maybe* there could be a mix of fuel and oxygen such that at normal pressure (whatever that is on planet X) it does not normally burn, but that when compressed in a jet engine it burns well.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Maybe. The possibility that came to mind for me is a very very low density atmosphere wouldn't catch fire under any circumstances simply because there is too much space between the molecules. Perhaps a ramjet could make use of such an atmosphere.

Comment: In any case even it such an atmosphere could exist (which I'm not sure about), I'm pretty certain that no such atmosphere does exist in our solar system.

Comment: Maybe at a sufficiently high altitude, you could have such a thin atmosphere that a flame couldn't propagate, but at lower altitude you'd have higher pressure, greater density, and the same first-spark-ignites-the-atmosphere situation. This may be approaching a question better on Worldbuilding.SE than here.

Comment: I very much doubt such an atmosphere could exist even at low density--even if it can't support flame you will get reactions sometimes when molecules bump into each other.  Thus it would not be stable.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: …and yet the atmospheric gas mix doesn't _need_ to be long term stable — it just needs to react slowly enough that other processes (biology, volcanism, photochemistry, etc.) can replenish it. After all, the Earth's atmosphere isn't thermodynamically stable either: it's mostly composed of dinitrogen and dioxygen, which react *very* slowly to form various nitrogen oxides. But the timescale for this reaction is longer than the biological cycle time for these gases. (Of course that's an endothermic reaction, so you can't really use it to drive an engine even if you catalyzed it.)

Comment: it is the Earth who has both hydrogen and oxygen in the atmosphere, the problem is that they are separated by tens of km elevation. The thermosphere and the exosphere are hydrogen-dominated, near the surface we have the nitrogen/oxygen mixture we are used to. And while I am not sure what the transition layer looks like, I am confident that no part of our atmosphere is able to burn by itself, no matter how much compressed. It is the photochemistry that will delete anything like this on a short timescale even if no sparks are available.

Comment: p.s. Jupiter is quite aviation-unfriendly anyway. Too much gravity, too little lift vs drag (hydrogen), too much turbulence, way too much clouds and no subsance good for filling a baloon that has to be lighter than the surrounding gas.

Comment: Feels like it's time to take out the fusion ramjet and build a plane that runs in Jupiter's upper atmosphere.

Comment: *the atmosphere was, by itself, flammable* - you see the problem there, right?

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on the other answer, you don't actually need **any** fuel *or* oxidizer to run a jet engine. Jet engines are just a type of [open-cycle heat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine) where the atmosphere is the working fluid and thrust happens by expelling it as [reaction mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_mass). Usually this is implemented as a form of [internal combustion engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine)— Fuel burns inside, that provides the heat, the exhaust shoots out the back, and you go forwards fastly, very speed.

But you can completely remove the fuel-burning step, and replace it with *any* equivalent source of heat, and it would still be a fully functional jet engine. [Nuclear reactors have been tried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Nuclear_Propulsion)— No oxygen-burning fuel at all, just a bundle of uranium that the air goes around. Or if you cut a transparent window out of the side of the combustion chamber, and you shone a strong enough laser into it, that could work too.

On Jupiter, you would indeed need to bring your own oxygen/oxidizer, and ingest hydrogen as fuel.

Comment: Or if we're talking science fiction, "burn" the hydrogen with a fusion reaction, no oxygen needed.  Only a tiny fraction of the hydrogen has to fuse to heat the rest of it a *lot*.  (But you'd need some kind of cold fusion shenanigans or else that airflow would cool the plasma too much...)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hm, indeed. Wouldn't strictly need to be cold fusion shenanigans either; You could localize the fusion to small volumes for very brief durations (E.G. pulsed Z-pinch powered by the turbine), as long as you're not overly insistent on continuous self-sustaining ram-compression-burning.

Comment: Yep. Even a battery attached to resistive heating elements would theoretically work. Though finding batteries with high enough capacity that can handle that much power draw will be a challenge (and the battery weight will be far more than carrying a bunch of kerosene or oxygen.)

Comment: that's clever, @PeterCordes !!

Comment: @PeterCordes Sadly ordinary hydrogen (protium) cannot be fused with protium except by relying on an incredibly rare weak reaction that converts one of the protons into a neutron, which makes a natural hydrogen fusion reactir extremely impractical. Well, I say "sadly" but it keeps our sun from burning all of its fuel extremely fast and going out in a blaze of glory, so perhaps it has its positives as well. ;)